# Fix errors related to platform_strong.dill

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I did `flutter build iOS` and I'm getting these 3 errors all related to the `platform_strong.dill` file:

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
    Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...          

    Compiler message:

    Error: SDK summary not found:
    file:///Users/[myusername]/Documents/Documents/development/flutter/bin/ca
    che/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk_product/platform_strong.dill
    .

    Error: Error when reading
    'file:///Users/[myusername]/Documents/Documents/development/flutter/bin/c
    ache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk_product/platform_strong.dil
    l': No such file or directory

    Error: Error when reading
    'file:///Users/[myusername]/Documents/Documents/development/flutter/bin/c
    ache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk_product/platform_strong.dil
    l': No such file or directory
```

It says that the file is not there, but it is:

[image]

Has anyone else experienced these errors? How would I go about fixing them? I have the latest `flutter` and I have Xcode 10.3.

Comment: Your screenshot directory is not the same as the one in the error messages...

Comment: @trojanfoe oh good catch.. ill see what's in that directory now

Comment: @trojanfoe please see updated it looks like there is only platform_strong.dill.S and .d no plain platform_strong.dill Is there a specific reason for that? Should I rename one of those to remove the .S?

Comment: To be honest I don't know.  I do know that `.S` is assembler language source and `.d` is a make dependency file and they cannot be renamed without consequences.

Comment: But like everything [Google gives some clue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20626).

Comment: @trojanfoe interesting, I did google this and I didn't find that. I'll look at it now

Comment: @trojanfoe `rm -fr flutter/bin/cache` worked! Would you like to create an answer that I can accept?

Comment: No, that's alright.  I was feeling in the dark myself :)  You can answer it yourself.

Comment: @trojanfoe Ok I answered it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the cache folder worked! `rm -fr flutter/bin/cache`. Then I ran `flutter build iOS` and all the errors related to the `platform_strong.dill` went away.